# Read xml file into csv format

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I'm trying to parse the following xml content into a csv format:

```
<order>
  <item>abc</item>
  <item>123</item>
  <item/>
  <item>000</item>
</order>
<order>
  <item>999</item>
  <item>333</item>
</order>
```

I was able to read the xml file using FileApi. Variable `text` holds the xml content. Can you offer some insights on how to parse each `<order>` tag into an array?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#fileUpload").change(function () {
                for (var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {

                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = function(e) {
                      var text = reader.result; 
                    }
                    reader.readAsText(this.files[i]);

                    //TODO
                    //1. find tag <order> 
                    //2. get all <item> text into an array
                    //3. separate array elements with a semicolon
                    //4. show array content in the div dataContainer + <br>
                    //5. repeat until there is no more <order> tags to parse

                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="file" id="fileUpload" multiple="multiple" />
    <div id="dataContainer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the expected output to be displayed in the div `dataContainer`:

```
abc;123;;000
999;333
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.find()` to get `<order>` elements, `.each()` to iterate `<item>` elements, concatenate `.textContent` of each element

```js
let xml = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <order>
    <item>abc</item>
    <item>123</item>
    <item/>
    <item>000</item>
  </order>
  <order>
    <item>999</item>
    <item>333</item>
  </order>
</root>`;

let str = "";

$(xml)
  .find("order")
  .each(function() {
    let item = $(this).find("item");
    item.each(function(i, el) {
      str += el.textContent + (i < item.length - 1 ? ";" : "");
    });
    str += "\n";
  });

console.log(str);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just store the data in a [Document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) and iterate over it the way you would with any other DOM? What you want to do looks kinda like [MDN's example of doing exactly that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Parsing_and_serializing_XML):

```
var sMyString = '<a id="a"><b id="b">hey!</b></a>';
var oParser = new DOMParser();
var oDOM = oParser.parseFromString(sMyString, "text/xml");

orders = oDOM.getElementsByTagName("order");
for (i = 0; i < orders.length(); i++) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

Or if you're feeling a bit more brave, you could use [XPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath) references with the oDOM object.